# Finding all possible Jordan forms from the Characteristic polynomial

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form, characteristic-polynomial

> Let A be a 7 x 7 matrix with characteristic polynomial $(t − 2)^4(3 − t)^3$. It is
> known that in the Jordan form of A, the largest blocks for both the eigenvalues are of order 2. Show that there are only two possible Jordan forms for A; and determine those Jordan forms.

Shouldn't there be 8 possible Jordan forms for the given matrix? The eigenvalue 3 will have one 2x2 block, and one 1x1 block. And the eigenvalue 2 can have two 2x2 blocks or, one 2x2 block and two 1x1 blocks, giving 8 possible arrangements between the two cases.

Or am I missing something? I also saw a similar question but the characteristic polynomial was $(t − 2)^4(t − 3)^3$ instead of $(t − 2)^4(3 − t)^3$. Is there any difference between these two?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Maybe it is implicitly assumed that Jordan forms differing only by permutation of blocks are equivalent.

Comment: I misread, but I find (1,1,1,1) and (1,1,2) and (2,2) for the $2$ eigenvalue and (1,1,1) and (1,2) for the $3$ eignevalue which gives 6 Jordan forms possible, is there another assumption ? Maybe they mean by are that they require the largest to be of rank 2

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is exactly the same as $(t-2)^4 (t-3)^3$ it is just a matter of convention $\det (XI_7 -A) $ or $\det(A - X I_7)$.

For your big question, it all depends on the numbers of ordered lists $(j_1 \leqslant \cdots \leqslant j_r)$ such that  $\sum_{i=1}^r j_i= 4$ and $(k_1 \leqslant \cdots \leqslant k_s)$ such that  $\sum_{i=1}^s k_i = 3$ (partitions).

Why? Because your Jordan decomposition will be given by diagonals
$$\operatorname{diag} (J(j_1,2), \dots , J(j_r,2),J(k_1,2), \dots , J(k_r,2))$$
with $j_i \leqslant j_{i+1}$ and $k_i \leqslant k_{i+1}$ where
$$J(n,\lambda) = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1 & 0 & \cdots &0\\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \ddots & 1 \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0& \lambda
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{of size } n \times n.$$
Analaysing the size of the Jordan Blocks gives you algonside with the kernel lemma gives
$$\dim \ker((A-2I_7)^4) = 4 =j_1 + \dots + j_r$$
$$\dim \ker((A-3I_7)^3) = 3 =k_1 + \dots + k_s$$

But you have another assumption: the largest Jordan block's size is two for each eigenvalue, which means that $j_r = 2$ and $k_s = 2$.

This gives you for $(j_1,\dots ,j_r)$:

- $(1,1,2)$
- $(2,2)$

And for $(k_1,\dots ,k_s)$:

- $(1,2)$

Which means you have $2 \times 1= 2$ possibilities! Which are
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&2&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&2&1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&2&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&3&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&3&1 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&3
\end{pmatrix} 
\qquad 
\begin{pmatrix}
2&1&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&2&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&2&1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&2&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&3&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&3&1 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&3
\end{pmatrix}$$